# Disable select options from collection_select dynamically using helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm new in Rails. So, I have a view and I got two collection_select fields

```
<%= f.collection_select :planA_id, Plan.order(:id),:id,:codename, {disabled:... %>
<%= f.collection_select :planB_id, Plan.order(:id),:id,:codename, {disabled:... %>
```

I want both values to be mutually exclusive, so when I select one option on the first dropdown, it should not appear on the second one. Is this possible with the option hash or does it require something special?

Thank you very much. Sorry for bad English!

Answer (score 0):

Use `jQuery` `onchange` function and check the value field,

```
$("#dropdown1").on('change', function(){
    if(this.val != ''){
        $("#dropdown2").prop("disabled", true);
    }else{
    // do something else 
    }
});
```

This is just an example showing the way how to proceed further.